# Personal Contact Forms

Tags: 7, forms, emails

What is the best way to get a 'Contact User' form on nodes like an ebay-ish 'Contact Seller' simple form?

I tried Contact / Contact Forms module, but I do not want a Sitewide Contact form to be accessible (don't want to use it) and I want Mollom/Captcha integration and sending limits for anonymous users.

I thought maybe I could do Webform, but I can't see a way to make the recipient dynamic (node author, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Privatemsg module](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg)